# Check the nature of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Check the nature of the series
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$

I find the limit of the nth term. I got zero, I don't have any hope. I tried Limit Comparison test, Ratio Test and Cauchy's n-th root test. None is working. Can you please help me.

Comment: Hint: Can you multiply the numerator and denominator by the same factor to simplify the numerator?

Comment: I'd start the summation at $n=1$ if I were you.

Comment: The general term behaves like $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$, so... Alternative approach: by summation by parts, the given series has the same behaviour of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n(n+1)}$, so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{n}=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)}\le \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n(\sqrt{n})}
\\ and
\\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n(\sqrt{n+1})}
\\now \ use \ comparison \ test...
$

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
consider
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n}
$
where
$1 >a > 0$.
This problem is the case
$a = \frac12$.

Since $x^a$ is monotonic,
and
$(x^a)' = a x^{a-1}
$,
$(n+1)^a-n^a
=\int_n^{n+1} (x^a)' dx
=\int_n^{n+1} ax^{a-1} dx
\lt a n^{a-1}
$
so
$\frac{(n+1)^a-n^a}{n}
\lt \frac{a n^{a-1}}{n}
= \frac{a }{n^{2-a}}
$
and the sum of these converges.